# Where are the files uploaded from gloud app deploy?

Tags: google-app-engine

Where do i access the files uploaded through running `gcloud app deploy`?

I may want to remove some files i uploaded too. How do i do that?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not Google tech support.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really select files to delete. The app is uploaded as a package to Google App Engine so we can serve your App Engine out. If you want to delete files, you will simply have to upload a new version without those files and then delete the old version.